# Google App engine Deploy Exception : Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

Error message :

------------ Deploying frontend ------------

Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\JAMESY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg5730205859174689794.tmp'
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Compiling jsp files.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.

Debugging information may be found in C:\Users\James Yang\AppData\Local\Temp\appengine-deploy1938777867658475857.log

I have added 
-vm
G:\Jdk8\bin\javaw.exe

in eclipse.ini

and My java_home is G:\Jdk8\bin\

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you have the [Java Development Kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (JDK) installed in your computer.
- Check if you have Java 8 installed, while trying to compile with Java 7, or viceversa. In other words, check if the JDK is set to the wrong version.
- Make sure the JDK is FIRST in your Path, by placing %JAVA_HOME%\bin at the beginning of your Path in your System variables.